# Animate a ToggleButton in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, animation, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 (non SilverLight) application inside of which I have a very simple XAML page.

```
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="TogBtn" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked" Unchecked="TogBtn_OnUnchecked">Off</ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

At the moment, the `ToggleButton` works as expected, when checked its background changes to the set accent color.

[image: toggle button]

How do I add an animation to this so that when clicked, the blue background color eases in.

Comment: Easy peasy. First extract the style template Right Click-Edit Template or just grab the default one if you want them all to behave the same and paste it here. Either adding a Duration to the Storyboard or an Easing in the VisualTransitions in the VisualStateManager should sort you the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chris and 2 hours of Googling and playing about with it, I figured it out:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Checked">
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.15" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Red"></ColorAnimation>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonCheckedBorderThemeBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonCheckedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Spent ages to get to the `Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"` otherwise it wouldn't work.

Grab [full template here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709930.aspx), then change the `<VisualState x:Name="Checked">` as shown above.

Thanks